# State stored in Android intent after the activity is resurrected

Tags: android

Supposing an Android activity has some properties stored in the intent that created that activity, what happens to that intent and the stored properties when the view of that activity is destroyed. Are they revived when that activity is recreated?

Comment: Can you brief more your question ?

Comment: Maybe I'll give you my specific example. I split my registration process into to two activities. The first activity sends the information that it has gathered to the second activity as properties in the intent that will start the second activity. The second activity can access that set of properties by calling the `getIntent` method and calling `getExtra` methods on the intent returned. I also have the task of maintaining state (ie let the user start where they left) when the activity is destroyed. I am wondering what would happen to the intent.

Answer (score 1):

As the `onDestroy()` method will be called all the details of that activity will be lost if you have not stored it into any persistent storages.

In an activity’s lifecycle,`onDestroy()` is the final call you receive before your activity is destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing (or called `finish()` on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space.

`onDestroy()` is called only when system is low on resources(memory, cpu time and so on) and makes a decision to kill your activity/application or when somebody calls `finish()` on your activity.

The `onDestroy` method should clean up all the resources those were acquired by the `onCreate` method and previously used by the now-destroyed activity.

Comment: mare wallpaper par image set karavani 6. To jevu hu set wallpaper btn par click karu to image save karavu 6u ane e j image retrive karavu and image overwrite karavu 6u ane e thay pan 6 but wallpaper ma previous image j set thay 6